# maximo anywhere platform artifacts

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I am using Maximo anywhere 7.5.2.1 . We noticed the platform-artifacts folders are not visible in eclipse Project explorer for some apps ( e.g. Inspection, Workexecution, Physical count) which ever were present in 7.5.2.0 but for the newly added apps this platform-artifact folder is visible in project explorer. Is there any way to make this visible for all apps?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful making changes to these files, as any change you make to the files will be overwritten on the next platform upgrade and will have to be manually applied, but it is possible.  Right click on the MaximoAnywhere/apps/WorkExecution directory and say Properties.  Under the Resource->Resource Filters section, remove the filter hiding the platform-artifacts directory.